# mongodb aggregate data columns with totals

Tags: mongodb, sum, dataset, aggregation-framework, aggregate

With the following aggregate query:

```
db.myColl.aggregate([
  {"$match":{ "State":"Iowa"}},
  {"$group":{ 
    "_id": "$County",
    "parks": {"$sum":"$ParkExp"}, 
    "roads": {"$sum": "$RoadExp"},
    "water": {"$sum": "$WaterExp"}
  }}
])
```

EDIT: And given some example data like this:

```
[
  {
    "State": "Iowa",
    "County": "Cass",
    "parks": 21,
    "roads": 22,
    "water": 11
  },
  {
    "State": "Iowa",
    "County": "Clay",
    "parks": 32,
    "roads": 32,
    "water": 33
  },
  {
    "State": "Iowa",
    "County": "Tama",
    "parks": 32,
    "roads": 38,
    "water": 19
  },
  {
    "State": "Texas",
    "County": "Cass",
    "parks": 18,
    "roads": 18,
    "water": 15
  },
  {
    "State": "Texas",
    "County": "Clay",
    "parks": 27,
    "roads": 26,
    "water": 14
  },
  {
    "State": "Iowa",
    "County": "Cass",
    "parks": 12,
    "roads": 32,
    "water": 29
  },
  {
    "State": "Iowa",
    "County": "Clay",
    "parks": 13,
    "roads": 21,
    "water": 11
  }
]
```

I'm able to return some useful data like this:

```
{"_id":"Cass", "parks":33, "roads":54, "water":40}
{"_id":"Clay", "parks":45, "roads":53, "water":44}
{"_id":"Tama", "parks":32, "roads":38, "water":19}
```

But how can I also add a total row to the results also? i.e.

```
{"_id":"Totals", "parks":110, "roads":145, "water":103}
```

I can loop through the first set of results easily enough, but I'd rather try and make Mongo do all the work.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by constant value to get aggregates from all documents and then run [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) to get a single array which contains 4 documents. After that you can run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get the same output as you're getting now but with one extra document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {
        "State": "Iowa"
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$County",
        "parks": {
            "$sum": "$parks"
        },
        "roads": {
            "$sum": "$roads"
        },
        "water": {
            "$sum": "$water"
        }
    }
},
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "Total",
            parks: { $sum: "$parks" },
            roads: { $sum: "$roads" },
            water: { $sum: "$water" },
            entries: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }    
    },
    {
        $project: {
            all: {
                $concatArrays: [ "$entries", [ "$$ROOT" ] ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "all.entries": 0
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$all"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$all"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FxJdO4YzOQR)

Comment: you answer doesn't work with the expanded dataset I added above, but it does work if I add another group at the end. if you add the group on the end of this solution, or come up with a better way, i'll accept your answer

https://mongoplayground.net/p/8To3fatVR9f

-and thanks for the speedy reply!

Comment: @wolstat I think I missed the moment when you updated your post, however it's the same approach: https://mongoplayground.net/p/k7zN4Bo9Erc

Comment: thanks so much for your help. Your amended solution adds the second group before this code, and mine after. Cheers.